# how to merge few observations from one dataset and few observations from another? SAS

Tags: merge, sas

I mean, I need not all observations. Only few from each dataset. For example: merge 1-5 observation from first dataset and 8-15 from second.

Data set 1:

```
Name COL 
Age1 15 
Age2 23 
Age3 65
```

Data Set 2:

```
Name COL 
Height1 155 
Height2 176 
Height3 145 
Height4 165
```

Comment: Please add sample data (input and desired output)

Comment: data set1:
Name       COL
Age1          15
Age2           23
Age3           65

Data set2:
Name         COL
Height1       155
Height2        176
Height3        145
Heigh4         165

desired output:

Age

Age1             15
Age2             23

Height

Height1        155

Age

Age3           65

Height

Height3        145
Heigh4         165

It's should be one new data set

Comment: Hard to understand. Suggest you edit your question with that information (will display better than in a comment) and any additional description you can provide.

Comment: Sorry, I'm at the first time here. I don't know how to put my comment like a program code, not like a text.
Sooorry

Comment: @Tanya, I added in part of your data set, but I can't follow your output data set. Please try to edit your code. You can add code by indenting the line 4 spaces and it will show as code.  You also need to explain your logic in more detail, why the first 5 and other records?

Comment: The table option `OBS=` allows you to limit the number of observations read from any dataset: `data test; merge ds1(OBS=5) ds2(OBS=8); by someVar; run;` . But not clear if that's what you're asking.